# Lookup the thesaurus entry by passing the synonym value

Tags: marklogic, thesaurus

I am using the MarkLogic Thesaurus functionality and struggling to fetch the thesaurus entry when passing one of the synonym in [`thsr.lookup()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/thsr:lookup).

For example : I have my thesuarus entry in the database as

```
<entry xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus">
 <term>Car</term>
 <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
 <synonym>
  <term>Ford</term>
  <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
 </synonym>
 <synonym>
  <term>automobile</term>
  <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
 </synonym>
 <synonym>
  <term>Fiat</term>
  <part-of-speech>noun</part-of-speech>
 </synonym>
```

Now when I execute the function as:

```
thsr.lookup('/thesaurusDoc.xml', 'Car')
```

I get the above entry element back as expected.

But when I try to lookup via synonym term, say:

```
thsr.lookup('/thesaurusDoc.xml', 'Fiat')
```

It doesn't return anything.

Can you please tell what am I doing wrong here and 
suggest any alternative if thesaurus functionality does not support the lookup via synonym?

Note: I'm using Marklogic Server Side Javascript functions and ML version is 9.0-8.1

I expect to get the `entry` element back as a result.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reverse-lookup, but that was never implemented. It is not difficult to scan through the thesaurus yourself, though. For exact matches you could do something like this:

```
doc("/thesaurusDoc.xml")
  /thsr:thesaurus/thsr:entry
    [thsr:synonym/thsr:term eq "Fiat"]
```

or if you want to use a query:

```
doc("/thesaurusDoc.xml")
  /thsr:thesaurus/thsr:entry
    [cts:contains(thsr:synonym/thsr:term, cts:word-query("Fiat"))]
```

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

Does the following lookup get any closer to meeting the requirement?

```
thsr.queryLookup('/thesaurusDoc.xml', cts.wordQuery('Fiat'))
```

See also https://docs.marklogic.com/thsr.queryLookup

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Looking back at the older answers, there is a certain elegance in being able to leverage thsr functions. A fairly straight-forward trick would be to just build a second thesaurus out of the first one, that flips around the terms, and their synonyms. So you get term 'Ford' with 'Car' as synonym.

Granted, if a reverse lookup could be added to thsr, that would have been even better.

HTH!